# Error with gdalUtils when starting R - there is no package called ‘gdalUtils’?

Tags: r, gdalutils

I have a problem starting R with the following error message "Error in loadNamespace(x): there is no package called ‘gdalUtils’" (see screen capture below). I have tried all the possibilities including downloading directly as a *.tar.gz file or through "devtools::install_github("gearslaboratory/gdalUtils")" but always end with the same error message provided above. I have also tried downloading old and new R versions but again the same error message is still there. I'm completely out of ideas and desperate for a solution. I'm using windows 10 on Dell laptop. I can see R is working on my Surface laptop without any problem but not on my Dell. Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Try `install.packages("gdalUtils")`

Comment: Thanks but not working with the following message "package ‘gdalUtils’ is not available for this version of R". I have tried different versions with the same results. I'm using R4.2.2.

Comment: `{gdalUtils}` was removed from CRAN (c.f. [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdalUtils/index.html)).

Comment: Thanks dimfalk, but what solution would be best to solve this problem?

Comment: Personally, I would not want to ride a dead horse and update my workflows to rely on packages which are being supported - but this is a matter of complexity and time, of course. But you could also try to install the latest archived version of `{gdalUtils}` from the [archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/gdalUtils/) and hope that it solves your issue (at least temporarily).

Comment: Thanks dimfalk. But even when trying to install any version I'm still receiving the same error message: "Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called 'gdalUtils'
Calls: loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/afana/Downloads/gdalUtils_2.0.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something in your R startup process is trying to load `gdalUtils`. On a clean computer this wouldn't happen, but you may have a personal startup file that survives R deinstall/reinstall. See:

```
?Startup
```

for details on how R runs things when it starts, there's lots of customisation options and they differ across operating systems.

Possibly running `traceback()` as the first thing in R after the error might tell you where the error is coming from which might help you track down which profile or startup file is responsible.

Comment: Hi Spacedman, Thanks a lot for your detailed reply. I have used traceback after the error and it returned back with 5 points but no clue what they mean.  Any feedback on this, please?  

5: stop(cond)
4: doWithOneRestart(return(expr), restart)
3: withOneRestart(expr, restarts[[1L]])
2: withRestarts(stop(cond), retry_loadNamespace = function() NULL)
1: loadNamespace(x)

Comment: No, I don't think that's useful - I was hoping it might have something like `source("/home/user/startup.R")` which would tell you where the startup procedure was trying to attach `gdalUtils`. You'll have to go through the startup procedure as detailed in the help and see if you can find it.